# Removing black line from bar diagram in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, diagram

I am trying to remove or move the black "line" which you can see on the some countries but I can't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the areas you want to remove do not have any data.

So you can control which Diagrams are visible in the *Rendering* tab of the Diagrams.

You need to untick "Show all diagrams" and set a rule for the "Show diagram" expression, for example where the data is over 0 (changing for the column that has data):

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, while i was trying something, I just inactive the show axis button and work it.But your solution also is working thanks a lot.

Comment: Can i set rule more than 1 feature? cuz i have 3 different field in the diagram.I wanna set the rule for instance total > 0, tv > 0, radio>0

Comment: "total" > 0 AND "tv" > 0 AND "radio" > 0